# Opening a hole the shape of an image

Tags: modeling

Good evening.

I am posing a question here, as I have a bit of a problem I'm facing with Blender. For starters, I'm not exactly experienced with modeling, so, even though I have managed to get myself past a larger number of roadblocks than I expected, some aspects of it still seriously elude me.

Mainly, I am trying to make a mesh that has a hole in it with the shape of a suit of cards. At the same time, I want that hole to have a mesh with that exact shape.
I have managed to import the image, and have it be its own plane. However, I am seriously confused on how:
1 - I can turn that plane into a shape;
2 - I can make a hole in the mesh I'm trying to mix it into

Would it be too much if I requested some assistance in this regard?

Thank you in advance.

m

[image]

Comment: Hi :). I seems you already have the heart shape modelled, so just cut it out of the card using boolean modifier. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Good evening. You didn't miss anything, I did. Like I mentioned, I'm sort of bumbling my way through this, so I didn't even know what that was. After looking it up, yes, that would definitely work wonders. However...
The heart shape is actually still a plane. Is it possible to turn it into a 3D shape (like if I wanted to turn a circle into a cilinder)?
I do owe you -massive- thanks for pointing me in that direction, though.

Comment: Never mind. I found out how. Solidify modifier.

Comment: Happy to help :). You can also directly cut out shapes with the [*Knife Project*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html) tool. Good luck with your project and welcome to Blender :))